# cant create DynamoDB client in spark Executor

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, spark-streaming

I had a requirement to load streaming data into DynamoDB Table. I tried Below Code.

```
  object UnResolvedLoad  {

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("unresolvedload").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    val tokensDf = spark.sql("select * from unresolved_logic.unresolved_dynamo_load")  
    tokensDf.foreachPartition { x => loadFunc(x) }
  }


    def loadFunc(iter : Iterator[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]) = {

      val client:AmazonDynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build()
      val dynamoDB:DynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client)
      val table:Table = dynamoDB.getTable("UnResolvedTokens")

      while(iter.hasNext){
        val cur = iter.next()
        val item:Item = new Item().withString("receiverId ", cur.get(2).asInstanceOf[String]).
                withString("payload_id", cur.get(0).asInstanceOf[String]).
                withString("payload_confirmation_code", cur.get(1).asInstanceOf[String]).
                withString("token", cur.get(3).asInstanceOf[String])

        table.putItem(item)

      }

}
```

}

When i Execute the spark-Submit it is not able to instantiate class. Below is error message. It says it could not instantiate Class.  Help is appreciated.
Is there a way we can save Spark DataSet into Amazon DynamoDB

```
, executor 5): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
        at com.dish.payloads.UnResolvedLoad$.loadFunc(UnResolvedLoad.scala:22)
        at com.dish.payloads.UnResolvedLoad$$anonfun$main$1.apply(UnResolvedLoad.scala:16)
        at com.dish.payloads.UnResolvedLoad$$anonfun$main$1.apply(UnResolvedLoad.scala:16)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17/07/19 17:35:15 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 26.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 26) on ip-10-176-225-151.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 5: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder) [duplicate 1]
17/07/19 17:35:15 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, ip-10-176-225-151.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 5): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientConfigurationFactory from class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.<clinit>(AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.java:30)
        at com.dish.payloads.UnResolvedLoad$.loadFunc(UnResolvedLoad.scala:22)
        at com.dish.payloads.UnResolvedLoad$$anonfun$main$1.apply(UnResolvedLoad.scala:16)
        at com.dish.payloads.UnResolvedLoad$$anonfun$main$1.apply(UnResolvedLoad.scala:16)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was Finally able to solve it by using lower  version of DynamoDB API. The EMR 5.7 only supports 1.10.75.1.  Below is the code that works fine for me.

```
object UnResolvedLoad  {

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("unresolvedload").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    val tokensDf = spark.sql("select * from unresolved_logic.unresolved_dynamo_load")  
    tokensDf.foreachPartition { x => loadFunc(x) }
  }


    def loadFunc(iter : Iterator[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]) = {

      val client:AmazonDynamoDBClient  = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
      val usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
      client.setRegion(usWest2)



      while(iter.hasNext){
        val cur = iter.next()

        val putMap = Map("receiverId" -> new AttributeValue(cur.get(2).asInstanceOf[String]), 
                          "payload_id" -> new AttributeValue(cur.get(0).asInstanceOf[String]),
                          "payload_confirmation_code" -> new AttributeValue(cur.get(1).asInstanceOf[String]),
                          "token" -> new AttributeValue(cur.get(3).asInstanceOf[String])).asJava

        val putItemRequest:PutItemRequest = new PutItemRequest("UnResolvedTokens",putMap)
        client.putItem(putItemRequest)
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Saves me a big time! thanks man. How did u think of that? it's really hard to think to this direction

Comment: I got that answer from AWS support Forum